# How do you forward a request from MVC/Zend to Wordpress?

Tags: model-view-controller, wordpress, zend-framework, forwarding

I'm pretty new to MVC and I haven't been able to figure out how to do this

Basically we have Zend/MVC App controlling some pages but WordPress handling others

> > Update
> >     Wordpress will be working like a CMS and not a blog. So there won't be any /blog urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using standard routing for your Zend app and pretty URLs for Wordpress, you will likely have to control this in your .htacess file (or in your Apache config).

Using mod_rewrite to send URLs (or URL patterns) to either Zend or WP is the easiest way to accomplish this.

For example, send requests that start with `blog/` to your Wordpress install and any other request would be handled by your Zend application's index.php file.